# File uploader saving blank images?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, asp-classic

I am creating a file uploader using JavaScript and Classic ASP. The image is imported into a canvas and then base64 URL is sent to the ASP script where it is to be decoded and downloaded.

I believe my AJAX request and base64 decoding are working properly. However, after downloading, viewing the image is blank. I do know some properties are working as whatever image dimensions are being uploaded are reflected in the download. I have verified the base64 URL is working as I can save export the image within the browser.

I have shortened the code for relevance sake.

Javascript:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.getElementById('filePreview').src = dataURL

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log("Image saved.");
    }
};
request.open("POST", "upload.asp", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("dataURL=" + dataURL);
```

Classic ASP:

```
base64String = Request.Form("DataURL")

Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)

dim bStream : set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
bStream.type =  1
call bStream.Open()

call bStream.Write( nodeB64.NodeTypedValue )
call bStream.SaveToFile(Server.Mappath("logos/test.png"), 2 )

call bStream.close()
set bStream = nothing
```

Comment: In the JS, debug dataURL and copy/paste that value as the src of an img tag. Does the image show up? Also the same for base64String after reading it from the request.

Comment: @KevinCollins I have verified the image is coming up before sending to AJAX - the image shows up perfectly. How can I verify this after it is sent to AJAX, as you are saying with base64String?

Comment: In the asp, just response.write Request.Form("DataURL")

Comment: @KevinCollins I have wrote out the information on the upload page. Writing `Response.Write(base64String)` outputs the DataURL while writing out `Reponse.Write("<img src='" & base64String & "'>)` outputs an image with no dimensions (maybe 1px by 1px) with a blank image. Any ideas? Thanks for your help this far.

Comment: Hey Gavin, could you compare the value of dataURL (from the javascript, just before the request.send line) with the value of base64String as received in the asp file. Wonder if it's getting messed up somehow.

Comment: @KevinCollins Do you recommend a good way of comparing them? The value of DataURL is nearly 1600 characters long. I have attempted using online text comparisons, but they don't work well with special characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143136/discussion-between-kevin-collins-and-gavin-youker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be plus signs in the string returned by `canvas.toDataURL`.

On the server side the plus signs get decoded into space characters. So the fix is to encode that string before sending it.

```
request.send("dataURL=" + encodeURIComponent(dataURL));
```

That turns "+" characters into "%2B" -- then interpreted by ASP as "+".